# return two list python?

Tags: python, list

I am not sure how the return works in the following compare function? Why can it return the format like this?

```
def func(self, num):
      num = sorted([str(x) for x in num], cmp=self.compare) 

def compare(self, a, b):
      return [1, -1][a + b > b + a]
```

Comment: Look at it this way: -1 if a + b > b + a else 1 (as covered by the answers – array indexing using equivalence of 1 / True and 0 / False).

Answer (score 6):

It's not returning two lists. It's returning one of the two values from the first list. Consider this rewriting:

```
def compare(self, a, b):
      possible_results = [1, -1]
      return possible_results[a + b > b + a]
```

It's taking advantage of the fact that `True` in Python is treated as the value `1`, and `False` is treated as the value `0`, and using those as list indices.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean value of *False* is zero and the boolean value of *True* is one.  They can both be used as indexes into a list:

```
# Normal indexing with integers
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][0]
'guido'
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][1]
'barry'

# Indexing with booleans
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][False]
'guido'
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][True]
'barry'

# Indexing with the boolean result of a test
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][5 > 10]
'guido'
>>> ['guido', 'barry'][5 < 10]
'barry'
```

Hope that makes it all clear :-)